# How many beers can be bought (using exchanges) starting with $n$?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

This is an extension/generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512083/the-number-of-bottles-of-beer-one-can-buy-with-10-after-exchanging-bottles-and).

Suppose

- $2 can buy 1 bottle of beer.
- 4 bottle caps can be exchanged for 1 bottle of beer.
- 2 empty bottles can be exchanged for 1 bottle of
  beer.

How many bottles of beer can you buy (and presumably drink) starting with $n$?  Write an exact formula for $n \in \mathbb Z$. (You are not allowed to "borrow" empty bottles and repay them.)

Comment: This question was literally asked 30 minutes ago http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512083/the-number-of-bottles-of-beer-one-can-buy-with-10-after-exchanging-bottles-and

Comment: Indeed... asked by *me*!

Comment: @Elliot: This question, as David says, is a generalization of the previous one.

Comment: ...and (I claim) worthy of being posted as a question in its own right.

Comment: My apologies. I assumed you might be from the same class or something.

Comment: I already gave a general answer to this problem in the link given by Elliot G above.

Answer (score 3):

For large $n$, for $\$2$ you can buy one bottle, which yields the equivalent of an additional $3/4$ bottle, so you get $\frac n2 + \frac 34 \cdot \frac n2 + (\frac 34)^2\frac n2  \dots$ Summing the geometric series, you can get $2n$ bottles for $\$n$.  It will always be less than this because you have a few bits left over (at least one bottle and one cap, maybe more).

Comment: We can try bounding the error. There is at most 1 bottle and 3 caps left, which is worth less than $\$6$ (3 bottles and 3 caps) minus 3 drinks. Hence this can buy at most another 9 drinks. Hence the number of bottles is in $[2n-9, 2n)$. (I'm sure we can do better than this.)

Comment: I checked the exact values on the computer and found that $2n -5$ seems to hold for all (even) $n \in [4,100]$.